# Installing gems issues - doesn't work and then all of a sudden works?

Tags: heroku, rubygems

I tried installing the heroku gem yesterday with "gem install heroku" and got the error message: ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'heroku' (>= 0) in any repository.

I just tried for the heck of it to install it today and all of a sudden it worked. This happened when I tried installing Git as well. What could be the reason for this delay/issue?

Answer (score 0):

When you do gem install it by default installs it from rubygems.org - perhaps there was a problem accessing the site when you attempted it.

However I suspect you didn't install Git from a gem command so it may suggest local network issues as opposed to anything else.

Comment: no, you're right i did not install Git from a gem but all I meant was that the same delay happened. It didn't work at first and then worked when I tried again later. Also, I am using my computer at work so maybe there are issues with the network (proxies, etc.) that could be interfering? Thanks for your input